# Magento2 interface error

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, interface

I do not understand what this error is and how it was produced ? I think it happend after I set up

```
SetEnv  MAGE_PROFILER   "html"
```

and after that I removed that line from the .htaccess file. And everything went to crap... I really do not understand why did the whole system broke... really...

In the result of this neither the frontend nor the admin is working.. as expected. Does anyone has a clue ? ?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManagerInterface\xfc\xff\xff\xff' 
not found  in /var/www/html/magento_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php on line 15
```

Comment: What version of magento and how did you deploy?

Comment: 2.0.2 CE. I already solved it by restarting apache server, don't know why it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you have a php bytecode cache enabled.

For example apc cache caches php bytecode and also php class pathes. This can lead to the behaviour, that you described.

Classes are searched in locations, where they are not anymore or code is executed, that is not up to date anymore.

In your dev env you should disable such modules (for example apc, Zend opcache, xcache etc. )

If you deploy to a productive env, the easiest way is indeed to restart the webserver

Answer (score 1):

Ok, If anyone has this weird problem in the future - this is the solution. Plain and simple - Restart Apache server (if you are using apache). Cleaning the cache and pub/static directory didn't help, but restarting apache did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar kind of scenario.

I received following error

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Training\Test\Model\Config\ConfigInterface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento215\app\code\Training\Test\Model\Config.php on line 5
```

I had following directory structure

```
Training\Model\Config\
```

I had an interface under the above directory as

```
Training\Model\Config\ConfigInterface.php
```

Content of Interface was following

```
<?php     

interface ConfigInterface {

    public function getMyNodeInfo();
}
```

when I updated my code to following the error message was gone.

```
<?php

namespace Training\Test\Model\Config;  // I missed this code line previously

interface ConfigInterface {

    public function getMyNodeInfo();
}
```